# get auto generated key, on save, using hibernate + spring mvc

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, get, return, primary-key

I am using **Spring MVC + Hibernate**

```
@Resource(name = "sessionFactory")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

// save
public <T> int save(T entity) throws DataAccessException {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.save(entity);

}
```

As New Record Save , New Primary Key generated which in auto increment (db.MySQL). I want to get and return the new auto incremented value with respect to the above method.

Update me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save method should return generated ID:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#save(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 5):

Try this instead. This works with latest Hibernate (version 4.1) also.

```
session.persist(object);
object.getId();
```

Comment: Why use 2 steps when you can get it in 1 step? Unlike `persist`, `save` returns the entity identifier.

Answer (score 0):

```
  //assumption: this method is adding a player into database and returns generated player id
    //Here player is object of class Player 
    public int addPlayer(Player player){
            int player_id;  //variable to store generated ID
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.persist(player);  //adding player
            player_id=player.getplayer_id();  //getplayer_id is the getter method for the variable player_id
            session. getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
            return player_id;
    }
```

Comment: try to edit your answer in a generic way: *player* entity has nothing to do with the question