# why session.save(object) does not set id automatically in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate as a JPA provider for my application and now I have a requirement that I need the id of recently stored request object, but when I do a `request.getId` it prints `null`.

```
System.out.println("before save : request id's = "+request.getId());   
session.save(request);    
System.out.println("after save : request id's = "+request.getId());
```

I followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25561681/hibernate-get-id-after-save-object).

**Output of this code:**

```
before save : request id's = null

after save : reqeust id's = null

public class Request implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
```

Comment: Try using `request = session.save(request)` and then `request.getId();`

Comment: Give us the DDL of the Table please.

Comment: Did you try to use the returned entity from the save call?

Comment: @TJ  save returns the identifier, not the entity.

Comment: @DrunkenPope: save returns the identifier, not the entity.

Comment: You're "using Hibernate for JPA" yet using Hibernate's own API *rather than* JPA API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the id is generated by the database it will only be there after the entity is actually written. Since hibernate tries to delay the actual write so it might safe some database-hits, `session.save()` will not necessarily trigger the id-generation.

Try adding `session.flush()` after the save and see if the id is populated then.