# Automatically connect PK and FK from a list

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I'm developing a java application that saves information in DB using procedures. I will give an example to show my doubt cause i'm kinda lost!

Lets pretend that i have this 2 different classes

```
public class Seg{
//variables
 ....

public class Dur{
//variables
private List list<Seg> //Lets pretend that Dur1 has 3 seg, and Dur1's PK = 1
....
```

And i want to save the information in DB. As the Dur1 has 3 seg and code PK=1 , so i will have 3 insert in seg that has a FK = 1 = Dur's PK

And my question is how can i automically, using a procedure, put a FK in the three seg inserts, assuming that (in java) i know all the matches between Seg and Dur(i have the list that connect them)

//Note: The pk is a attribute defined in the procedures with a sequence

I fear that some may not understand the question but in fact im a little bit confuse

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example (and the focus on the FK) makes it not clear if you try define a plain PL/SQL layer to handle elementary CRUD (in PL/SQL called also TAPI) or if you intend to encapsulate some kind of business logic.

In the former case you may rethink your approach and have a look on some kind of [ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25561681/hibernate-get-id-after-save-object).

Don't understand me incorrect, I'm not trying to answer your question with "do something else". My point is, there are tons of experience with your situation (database assigned keys) in ORM, so simple search links similar to the above and adapt it to your PL/SQL solution.

In my opinion, you will need to provide an *output parameter in the procedure storing  the parent class returning the sequence assigned PK* and *pass this value in the procedure for storing the child classes*.

Comment: so you are saying something like this: insert one (the mother class), procedure to get the PK and another insert to the childs where i put the result of the previous procedure in FK field?

Comment: @Mark yes, if you jave a parent child relationship(FK constraint),  this is the typical way.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Marmite Bomber , for understanding my doubt and help me!

Answer (score 0):

> Hey i tried to illustrate your scenario with an example. Hope it
>   helps. Please pardon any syntax error since i dont have workspace
>   currently.

```
--Drop any existing object with same name
DROP TABLE A1PK;

DROP SEQUENCE A1PK_seq;

-- Seq creation
CREATE SEQUENCE A1PK_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

-- Provding req privileges
GRANT SELECT ON INFRA_OWNER.A1PK_seq TO PUBLIC;

--Root table creation
CREATE TABLE AIK
(PK_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
PK_NAME VARCHAR2(100));

--Drop existing object
DROP TABLE FK1;

--Create Child table
CREATE TABLE FK1
(
PK_ID NUMBER,
PK_ADD1 VARCHAR2(100),
PK_ADD2 VARCHAR2(100)
);

--Drop any existing constraints if any with same name
ALTER TABLE FK1
DROP CONSTRAINT FK_PK;

--Adding foreign key for child table
ALTER TABLE FK1
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PK FOREIGN KEY(PK_ID) REFERENCES AIK(PK_ID);


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_into_child_tables
(p_seg1 IN VARCHAR2,
 p_seg2 IN VARCHAR2,
 p_seg3 IN VARCHAR2,
 p_root_val IN VARCHAR2)
 AS 
 lv_long LONG;
 lv_seq PLS_INTEGER;
 BEGIN
  SELECT INFRA_OWNER.A1PK_SEQ.NEXTVAL 
  INTO lv_seq 
  FROM DUAL;

  INSERT
  INTO INFRA_OWNER.AIK VALUES
    (
      lv_seq,
      p_root_val
    );

  FOR I IN
  (SELECT a1.OWNER,
      a1.CONSTRAINT_NAME,
      a1.TABLE_NAME
    FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS a1
    WHERE A1.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME IN
      (SELECT a2.CONSTRAINT_NAME
      FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS a2
      WHERE a2.TABLE_NAME    = 'AIK'
      AND a2.constraint_type = 'P'
      )
    ORDER BY A1.TABLE_NAME
  )
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO '||I.OWNER||'.'||I.TABLE_NAME||' VALUES ('||lv_seq||','||''''||lv_seg1||''''||','||''''||lv_seg2||''''||')';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO '||I.OWNER||'.'||I.TABLE_NAME||' VALUES ('||lv_seq||','||''''||lv_seg1||''''||','||''''||lv_seg2||''''||')';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO '||I.OWNER||'.'||I.TABLE_NAME||' VALUES ('||lv_seq||','||''''||lv_seg1||''''||','||''''||lv_seg2||''''||')';
  END LOOP;
END;
```