# Not getting value from MySQL DB and its working in Oracle DB using JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, generator, auto-increment

I'm currently using `JPA` with `Oracle DB` and it's working fine. Now I want to migrate the db to `Mysql`.

With OracleDB

```
  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "TASKID_GENERATOR", 
  sequenceName = "TASK_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = 
  "TASKID_GENERATOR")
  @Column(name = "TASK_ID")
  private long taskId;
```

In MySQL,

```
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     @Column(name = "TASK_ID")
     private long taskId;
```

I set `taskId` as `auto_increment` in the DB. But it's not working- `taskID` is getting update in DB, but I'm not able to get it from DB by getter and setter. Even if I assign `insertable = false, updatable = false` it's still the same behavior and `taskID` is using several table as a foreign key.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Please check the size of the ID in mysql table, the generated value size is big, so some time MySQL ID cannot persist it for the big size . I thing when the db is MySQL , it has it inbuilt auto generated id ,you can use that also

Comment: `But its not working` what exactly is not working? The insert? The update? Please clarify what you are able to do and what not

Comment: @Anupam Biswas, Oracle DB,TASK_ID is number(8,0) and I tried MySQL with BIGINT(8) and INT(8).But still same.Value is generated from DB side and not getting through getter and setter.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer,TASK_ID is inserting successfully in MySQL through auto_increment and @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY),But the issue is TASK_ID is not getting from DB through the code and same code is working in Oracle DB

Comment: What is the error message if there is one?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer,
No error message,TASK_ID i am getting as null.This is method to calling that
public TaskID findByPrimaryKey(long TaskId) {
  return em.find(TaskID.class, taskId);

Comment: whole entity `null` or just the `id`

Comment: so POST your code doing the persist + retrieve and the associated LOG messages in the JPA provider log. This is sometimes referred to as "debugging"

Comment: @XtremeBaumer,Actually the process is after giving all the input and click on save button then id will generated.After that we are trying to get only id and displaying.In that process its getting null using JPA.

Comment: You don't need to query the database for that. [This Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25561681/hibernate-get-id-after-save-object) shows you what you need to do