# How to get an autogenerated Id that I just inserted in the data base (Java)

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I know there are similar questions but I could not find it in java, here's my problem, I have a table called "transactions" which has an autogenerated Id [COT_Id] and I have and intermediate table [USER_TRANS] with the following columns: [COT_Id], [USER_Id] which makes a relationship between transaction table and user table, and I need to insert a new value in transaction, which it`s done already, now once it's inserted I need to get the auto generated Id in order to insert it in the intermediate table, here's my code:

```
  Transaction transaccion = new Transaction();
                 transaccion.setMvg_id(mvg_id);
                 aproCvv = generalService.getCardByCvv(cvv, cardNum);
                 transaccion.setCrd_id(aproCvv);
                 transaccion.setCot_amount(cot_amount);
                 transaccion.setCot_cuotas(cuotas);
                 transaccion.setCcr_id(ccr_id);
                 transaccion.setCot_authorizationNumber(numeroauto);
                 Date dateAct = new Date();
                 transaccion.setCot_CreateDate(dateAct);
                 transaccion.setEsb_id(esb_id);
                 transaccion.setCot_Ip(ipRemoto);
                 transaccion.setCot_cashUser(cot_cashUser);
                 transaccion.setCot_Reference(cot_Reference);
                 transaccion.setChn_id(chn_id);
                 transaccion.setCot_reverseReference("5454");
                 transaccion.setCot_transactionPin("566546df");
                 transaccion.setTrs_id(54);

                 if(resultado) {

                     transactionService.saveTrans(transaccion);

                    //here's where I need the autogenerated Id (transId)
                     generalService.saveUserTrans(udID, transId, 1);
```

Comment: Please have a look at the following:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25561681/hibernate-get-id-after-save-object