# How to get row value(s) back after db insert?

Tags: postgresql, go

I am using Golang to insert data into a DB. basically my query looks like below

```
var cols = "(col1, col2, col3)"
var values = "($1, $2, $3)"
var query = fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO %s %s VALUES %s", myTable, cols, values)

res, err := db.Exec(query, thing.val1, thing.val2, thing.val3)
```

The only things available from `res` are lastInsertId and # of rows affected. But what I need is the rows affected. The reason being is that I insert data into a psql database which has an AUTOINCREMENT id column - so I want the data back with that.

For example - with Java hibernate I can do what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25562185/6393275) answer explains. I don't have to re-query the DB for the ID.

EDIT: I tried to use the lastInsertId method and got this error

> LastInsertId is not supported by this driver

Comment: would `res.LastInsertId()` return the autoincremented ID? if not, perhaps do a select right after or use the `RETURNING col1, col2, ...` construct in a db like PostgreSQL

Comment: Add your database engine tag, @alex.  What is  this, mysql, postresql, other?

Comment: added psql. Also added java ref. for hibernate which does something similar

Comment: `db.Query` or `db.QueryRow` ?

Comment: You can use the `RETURNING` clause in `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` queries to get the rows affected. If you use the `RETURNING` clause you have to use `db.Query` or `db.QueryRow`, that means that you should NOT use `db.Exec`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you just want the auto-incremented value(s) in a column called `id` and this is an insert with the [pq driver](https://github.com/lib/pq)

```
var cols = "(col1, col2, col3)"
var values = "($1, $2, $3)"
var query = fmt.Sprintf(
    "INSERT INTO %s %s VALUES %s RETURNING id",
    myTable, cols, values,
)
var id int
if err := db.QueryRow(
    query,
    thing.val1, thing.val2, thing.val3,
).Scan(&id); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println("ID: ", id)
```

For multiple inserts:

```
var cols = "(col1, col2, col3)"
var values = "($1, $2, $3),($4, $5, $6)"
var query = fmt.Sprintf(
    "INSERT INTO %s %s VALUES %s RETURNING id",
    myTable, cols, values,
)
var ids []int
rows, err := db.Query(
    query,
    thing.val1, thing.val2, thing.val3,
    thing.val4, thing.val5, thing.val6,
)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
for rows.Next() {
    var id int
    if err := rows.Scan(&id); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    ids = append(ids, id)
}
fmt.Println("IDs: ", ids)
```

Answer (score 5):

`res.LastInsertId()` is not supported in Postgres Driver. However, It is supported in MySQL Driver.

`db.Exec()` doesn't return last inserted id but `db.QueryRow()` does.

For better understanding you can refer this [link](https://github.com/lib/pq/issues/24).

Here, I added one example which might help you.

```
var id int
err := db.QueryRow("INSERT INTO user (name) VALUES ('John') RETURNING id").Scan(&id)
if err != nil {
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you your answer was good but I selected the other one because it also showed an example for multiple values insert