# How to handle postgres query error with pgx driver in golang?

Tags: go, pgx

I read this [official guide about error handling](https://github.com/jackc/pgx/wiki/Error-Handling)

i applied it

```
err := db.connection.QueryRow("INSERT INTO articles(uri) VALUES ($1)", article.URI).Scan()
if err != nil {
    var pgErr *pgconn.PgError
    if errors.As(err, &pgErr) {
        fmt.Println(pgErr.Message) // => syntax error at end of input
        fmt.Println(pgErr.Code)    // => 42601
    }
}
```

Code doesn't work, my app doens't print anything. But postgres log has `ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "articles_uri_key"`

Ok, i can use standart golang method:

```
err := db.connection.QueryRow("INSERT INTO articles(uri) VALUES ($1)", article.URI).Scan()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

One problem, it prints `no rows in result set` when no errors in postgres log.

I tried replace
`if err != nil` with `if err != errors.New("no rows in result set")`,

it still prints `no rows in result set`

Answer (score 1):

Use pgx.ErrNoRows

```
if err != pgx.ErrNoRows {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please modify your question and make it appropriate.

Duplicate key value is a valid error. If you want to remove the error either you should avoid `duplicate` entry or remove `unique` constraint from it.

Using pgx with database/sql, pgx is simply acting as driver.The `sql.ErrNoRows` error is being returned from the database/sql library. `pgx.ErrNoRows` is only returned when calling a `pgx` function directly. As database/sql will bubble up some errors from the driver.

```
sqlStatement := `
   INSERT INTO articles (uri)
    VALUES ($1)
    RETURNING id`
    id := 0
   //make sure what type of data you want to scan you should pass it inside scan()
    err = db.QueryRow(sqlStatement, article.URI).Scan(&id)
    if err != nil {
    if err == sql.ErrNoRows {   //pgx.ErrNoRows
        // there were no rows, but otherwise no error occurred
    } else {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
    fmt.Println("New record ID is:", id)
```

For better understanding or for multiple rows please refer this link : [How to get row value(s) back after db insert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70208076/how-to-get-row-values-back-after-db-insert/70209795#70209795)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's old question, but I just found the solution
do not use

```
 var pgErr *pgconn.PgError
```

try to use

```
var pgErr pgx.PgError
```

instead