# Get Autogenerated Id on save using Spring boot 1.5.9 and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have implemented persistence using `JpaRepository`. I want the Id generated on saving any data without using any extra DB operation. I have also followed [this-approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18354157/get-auto-generated-key-on-save-using-hibernate-spring-mvc) but its returning 0 (Zero) everytime instead of the actual id. Below is my implementation:

My Model class:

```
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Entity
@Table(name = "registrations", schema = "sqs")
public class RegistrationsEntity implements Serializable {
    private long rId;
    private String rName;
    private String rPassword;
    private String rEmail;
    private Date rCreatedAt;
    private Date rUpdatedAt;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "r_id")
    public long getrId() {
        return rId;
    }

    public void setrId(long rId) {
        this.rId = rId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "r_name")
    public String getrName() {
        return rName;
    }

    public void setrName(String rName) {
        this.rName = rName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "r_password")
    public String getrPassword() {
        return rPassword;
    }

    public void setrPassword(String rPassword) {
        this.rPassword = rPassword;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "r_email")
    public String getrEmail() {
        return rEmail;
    }

    public void setrEmail(String rEmail) {
        this.rEmail = rEmail;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @CreatedDate
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "r_created_at", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    public Date getrCreatedAt() {
        return rCreatedAt;
    }

    public void setrCreatedAt(Date rCreatedAt) {
        this.rCreatedAt = rCreatedAt;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @LastModifiedDate
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "r_updated_at", nullable = false)
    public Date getrUpdatedAt() {
        return rUpdatedAt;
    }

    public void setrUpdatedAt(Date rUpdatedAt) {
        this.rUpdatedAt = rUpdatedAt;
    }
}
```

My DAO class:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class RegistrationDAOImpl implements IRegistrationDAO {

    @Autowired
    RegistrationRepository registrationRepository;

    @Override
    public void insertRegistration(RegistrationsEntity registrationsEntity) {

        registrationRepository.save(registrationsEntity);

        try {
            System.out.println("Reg Id " + registrationsEntity.getrId());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My Service class:

```
@Service
public class RegistrationServiceImpl implements IRegistrationService {

    @Autowired
    private IRegistrationDAO iRegistrationDAO;

    @Override
    public boolean addRegistration(RegistrationsEntity registrationsEntity) {

        iRegistrationDAO.insertRegistration(registrationsEntity);
        return true;
    }
}
```

My Repository Interface:

```
public interface RegistrationRepository extends JpaRepository<RegistrationsEntity, Long> {
}
```

My Controller:

```
@Controller
public class DummyController {

    @GetMapping(value = "regtest")
    @ResponseBody
    public void regtest() {

        RegistrationsEntity entity = new RegistrationsEntity();
        entity.setrName("ssssss");
        entity.setrPassword("12345");
        entity.setrEmail("ssss@rrrr.net");

        iRegistrationService.addRegistration(entity);
    }
}
```

Please Help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Id should be declared like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
```

Also autoincrement property should be set in database schema (eg in MySQL).

Thre reason you are getting 0 is most probably because database is not autogenerating that id setting it to default 0. Most probably you dont have even set PK in your database schema.

Comment: @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) is what i missed, my backend was good with autoincrement and serial. Thanks a lot...